# edit equations in PowerPoint 2011 (mac) that were saved in PowerPoint 2010 (windows)

Tags: macos, mac, microsoft-office, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2011

I'm trying to edit a file that was saved in PowerPoint 2010, on Windows. I'm using PowerPoint 2011 on Mac OSX.

The problem is that any text box that has an equation in it is un-editable (rendered as an image).

Is there anything I can do to make this work (other than re-writing the text boxes that contain equations)?

Comment: You would need a program that will OCR the image and let you edit it, then reinsert it. So no, if it's an image you cannot. Why did it render as image?

Comment: I don't remember offhand, but does Mac PPT 2011 have an Equation Editor?  If not, then that's your answer.  If it does, then verify that you're not saving your presentation as PPT rather than PPTX.

Comment: It does have an equation editor, @steve. Seems to work sort of like the Office 2003 equation editor. Ended up rewriting the slides that have equations in them. There seems to be a helpful little bug that lets you edit text-boxes that have equations - just edit a different text box (without equations) and then click the one with equations - but note that after changing anything in such a text box, saving the file and reopening it - all equations in the edited text box will vanish!

Comment: Ah, ok.  The EE changed between 2003 and 2007 on the Windows side; typically, anything that won't fly going backward turns into a picture, so that's likely what you're seeing.  I wonder if a Copy/Paste Special/As EMF on the windows side would turn it into something more useful on the Mac side.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't experiment as I'm traveling and I only took my Mac with me...